# curl error only on RHEL 7.1 but not on CentOS or Ubuntu

Tags: ssl, curl, nessus

We have a Nessus server running on Windows 10.  I am trying to run curl commands from linux.  These commands used to work fine until an upgrade of the Nessus server a few weeks back.

This example command works fine on Ubuntu 14.04 and CentOS 7.2 but not on RHEL 7.1.  If it was a certificate issue, it should happen on the ubuntu and CentOS as well.  All the OS's are vm's on the same vcenter.  Only the Nessus is running on a physical machine. Any tips would be very helpful.  Thanks!!

```
curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length
```

Command to get the above error

```
curl -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"user"," password": "user123"}' https://10.0.0.10:8834/session
```

I tried disabling the firewall and selinux on the RHEL as well. No use.

Answer (score -1):

Solved!  A `yum update` fixed it.  :)